# Unable to assign property Value. string expected, got nil

Tags: lua, compiler-errors, roblox

I'm trying to create a rank in leader board stats and the value should be `StringValue`, however I'm receiving this error:

```
Unable to assign property Value. string expected, got nil
```

How can I fix it and what's the problem?

I would highly appreciate any help.

**Script:**

```lua
-- Rank
local Rank = Instance.new("StringValue", stats)
Rank.Name = "Rank"
Rank.Value = "Newbie"
Rank.Parent = leaderstats

local success = nil
local playerData = nil
local attempt = 1

repeat
    success, playerData = pcall(function()
        return DataBase:GetAsync(player.UserId)
    end)

    attempt += 1
    if not success then
        warn(playerData)
        task.wait(3)
    end
until success or attempt == 5

if success then
    print("Connected to database")
    if not playerData then
        print("Assigning default data")
        playerData = {
            ["Coins"] = 0,
            ["Mcoins"] = 0,
            ["Exp"] = 0,
            ["Level"] = 1,
            ["Rank"] = "Newbie",
            ["ExpNeeded"] = Level.value * 200,
        }
    end
    sessionData[player.UserId] = playerData

else
    warn("Unable to get data for", player.UserId)
    player:Kick("Unable to load your data. Try again later")
end

Rank.Value = sessionData[player.UserId].Rank
Rank.Changed:Connect(function()
    sessionData[player.UserId].Rank = Rank.Value
end)
```

Comment: You should print out the table of data you get back from a successful load. The error is telling you that the player's data table doesn't have a field named "Rank"

Answer (score 0):

You should try to declare the sessionData first if haven't and give default value in case success = false

Comment: If it doesn't succeed, the player is kicked from the game.

Comment: I noticed that but the code shown isn't complete